# Issue connecting to PG Database with WSL

Tags: postgresql, express, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I am hosting a post gres database on Windows, my development is done through WSL and I am attempting to use node-postgres to connect my backend to my database with Express but I keep receiving this error:

```
 errno: -111,
  code: 'ECONNREFUSED',
  syscall: 'connect',
  address: '127.0.0.1',
  port: 5432
```

I checked my netstat and all possible credentials, but everything is correct. I have heard there may be an issue with inbound connections coming from WSL to Windows due to WSL using some sort of dynamic IP system, but I am not sure.

Comment: Either the server is not running, or it is running on a different address or port, or `listen_addresses` does not contain the loopback interface, or your network configuration prevents the connection. Easy to determine once you have learned the basics of the art of debugging.